# How is handled escape values(like \nnn,\xnn) in string literal?

Tags: c, string-literals

How is handled escape values(like \nnn,\xnn) in string literal? consider

```
"foo \x61 \042 baa"
```

Is `\x61` and `\042` converted to decimal base and stored in a memory location? and is translated to `"foo 97 34 baa"` if so,is this at compile-time? does it applies to all escape characters? if don't,how is this handle by the C compiler?

Comment: For reference: C Standard, 6.4.4.4 Character constants and 6.4.5 String literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All characters in (or not in, for that matter) a string are just numbers. In c a string is stored as an array of 8-bit numbers with a 0 at the end to indicate the end of the string (the "null terminator").
Escape sequences are handled in precisely the same manner as regular characters: their ascii value is stored in an array. In your example, the following are identical:

```
"foo \x61 \042 baa"
"foo a \" baa"

{ 'f',  'o',  'o',  ' ', '\x61',  ' ', '\042',  ' ',  'b',  'a',  'a', '\0'}
{ 'f',  'o',  'o',  ' ',    'a',  ' ',    '"',  ' ',  'b',  'a',  'a', '\0'}
{ 'f',  'o',  'o',  ' ',   0x61,  ' ',    042,  ' ',  'b',  'a',  'a', '\0'}
{0x66, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x20,   0x61, 0x20,   0x22, 0x20, 0x62, 0x61, 0x61,  0x0}
{ 102,  111,  111,   32,     97,   32,     34,   32,   98,   97,   97,    0}
{0146, 0157, 0157,  040,   0141,  040,    042,  040, 0142, 0141, 0141,    0}
```